# Prove if true and find a counterexample if false (disproofs/algebraic proofs)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For all sets $A, B, C$

$$A- (B-C) = (A-B) -C$$

Now my books says it is false and begins showing a counter example, but how do you know it is false by just looking at it? Would you go about proving it first and then if a proof can't be found, make up a counter example?

The proof I think would start out...

$x$ in $A$ and not ($x$ in $B$ and $x$ not in $C$)=

Comment: What happens if $A=B=C$ ?

Answer (score 3):

There are several possibilities:

1. You have enough intuition to immediately see that it looks unlikely to be true, so try to build a counterexample.
2. You try drawing some simple examples (in this case probably in the form of Venn diagrams) to see if you accidentally find a counterexample. If it turned out that the statement was true, this method might also give you some clues as to why.
3. The statement looks similar to other statements that you know are false. There isn't anything extremely obvious in your example, although if you replaced the sets by numbers and the set subtractions by usual subtraction, the resulting expression would be false (i.e. subtraction of integers is non-associative). This is obviously not a proof that your statement is false, but maybe makes it look less plausible.
4. You mistakenly decide the statement is true, and try to prove it. Your proof inevitably breaks down, but possibly in such a way as to tell you what a counterexample looks like.

There are probably more things you can do, but these are all good strategies for dealing with "prove or find a counterexample" type questions.

Comment: If you don't mind could you make a venn diagram for this particular example. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @user108969 The completely standard 3-circle Venn diagram (including some triple overlap) will work.

Comment: [@user108969: Note that Venn diagrams are great for communicating and constructing proofs or counter-examples, but should not *themselves* be proofs in this context (or sometimes even counter-examples); a proof should deal with the most general case and, besides a few rare exceptions, Venn diagrams don't do that.]

Comment: @MattPressland I understand the shape of the venn diagram, but am confused to which circles will be filled in due to the double minus (A-(B-C))

Comment: @Shaun I agree that a Venn diagram will very rarely provide a proof, but I'm not sure what you mean when you say they sometimes can't be counterexamples. (Unless you just mean that sometimes there won't exist a counterexample to the statement consisting of a collection of subsets of the plane, in which case I agree.)

Comment: @Matt Pressland: That's the kind of exception I had in mind, although, to be honest, I was hedging my bets more than anything :)

Comment: @user108969 For the right hand side, take the circle $A$, remove everything in $B$, and then remove everything in $C$; in particular, nothing from $C$ is left. The left hand side is slightly harder. Take the circle $B$, and remove everything in $C$; call the result $D$. Then remove from $A$ everything lying in $D$. This time you have some elements of $C$ left, so the two sets are not equal. (Sorry I haven't given you a picture; I don't have time right now to make it and learn how to upload pictures to MSE).

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case I would focus on $C$. It’s immediately clear that $(A\setminus B)\setminus C$, is disjoint from $C$, i.e., contains no points of $C$. On the left, $B\setminus C$ contains no points of $C$, and it’s what I’m subtracting from $A$, so I’m not removing any points of $C$ from $A$. If $A$ contains some point $c$ of $C$, then $A\setminus(B\setminus C)$ is still going to contain that point, but $(A\setminus B)\setminus C$ isn’t.

Then I try to build a specific counterexample based on this idea. I might let $A=C=\{c\}$ and $B=\varnothing$, just to keep things simple. Does it work?

$$A\setminus(B\setminus C)=\{c\}\setminus(\varnothing\setminus\{c\})=\{c\}\setminus\varnothing=\{c\}\;,$$

and

$$(A\setminus B)\setminus C=(\{c\}\setminus\varnothing)\setminus\{c\}=\{c\}\setminus\{c\}=\varnothing\;,$$

so it works exactly as expected.

I could also have done a quick check of ‘extreme’ special cases. What happens if $A=\varnothing$? Nothing useful: both sides are $\varnothing$. What if $B=\varnothing$? Then

$$A\setminus(B\setminus C)=A\setminus(\varnothing\setminus C)=A\setminus\varnothing=A\;,$$

and

$$(A\setminus B)\setminus C=(A\setminus\varnothing)\setminus C=A\setminus C\;.$$

Certainly those don’t have to be equal; for instance, I could take $A=C\ne\varnothing$, and they would be unequal.